# Trying to add contacts via ActiveCampain API (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, request, guzzle, activecampaign

I´m trying to integrate the RESTFUL API of ActiveCampaing to my Laravel environment, but I haven’t been so luckier, I'm using GuzzleHttp to make the requests, this is the [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZFL8.png) and my code:

```
 $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([‘base_uri’ => ‘https://myaccount.api-us1.com/api/3/’]);

$response = $client->request('POST', 'contacts', [
    'headers' => [
        'Api-Token' => 'xxx',
        'api_action' => 'contact_add',
    ],
    'json' => [
        'email' => 'test2021@test.com',
        'first_name' => 'Julian',
        'last_name' => 'Carax',
    ]
]);

echo $response->getStatusCode(); // 200
echo $response->getBody();
```

Hope you could help me! :D

Comment: use try catch blocks and catch the ClientException, then so $e->->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents(); to get complete error message check which fields are required from the api docs & check which you are not sending then change your code & rerun the requests it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not sending the data in correct format,
from the docs https://developers.activecampaign.com/reference#contact

```
{
    "contact": {
        "email": "johndoe@example.com",
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "phone": "7223224241",
        "fieldValues":[
          {
            "field":"1",
            "value":"The Value for First Field"
          },
          {
            "field":"6",
            "value":"2008-01-20"
          }
        ]
    }
}
```

So create an array with key contact.

```
$contact["contact"] = [
        "email" => "johndoe@example.com",
        "firstName" => "John",
        "lastName" => "Doe",
        "phone" => "7223224241",
        "fieldValues" => [
            [
                "field"=>"1",
                "value"=>"The Value for First Field"
            ],
            [
                "field"=>"6",
                "value"=>"2008-01-20"
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

Use try catch blocks as then you can catch your errors

```
try{
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(["base_uri" => "https://myaccount.api-us1.com/api/3/"]);

    $response = $client->request('POST', 'contacts', [
        'headers' => [
            'Api-Token' => 'xxx',
            'api_action' => 'contact_add',
        ],
        'json' => $contact
    ]);
    
    if($response->getStatusCode() == "200" || $response->getStatusCode() == "201"){
        $arrResponse = json_decode($response->getBody(),true);
    }
} catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e){
    $error['error'] = $e->getMessage();
    if ($e->hasResponse()){
        $error['response'] = $e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents();
    }
    // logging the request
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::error("Guzzle Exception :: ", $error);
    // take other actions
} catch(Exception $e){
    return response()->json(
            ['message' => $e->getMessage()],
            method_exists($e, 'getStatusCode') ? $e->getStatusCode() : 500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check at the [API docs](https://developers.activecampaign.com/reference#contact) that the fields `email`, `first_name`, `last_name` are under a `contact` node.

So make a `contact` array, put these fields inside and you should be fine.

The fields for first and last name are written line `firstName` and `lastName` - camelCase, not snake_case like you did.

**Official php client**

You should probably use the official [ActiveCampaign php api client](https://github.com/ActiveCampaign/activecampaign-api-php) - that would make your life easier.